# How to host laravel project in a folder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache

i am trying to host my laravel 5.8 app on server folder uploaded it through filezila...but not able to run the project all it shows that 403 of server page

This is current directory deploying my app in excapade

[image: This is current directory deploying my app in excapade]

thats what i am trying to do

[image: thats what i am trying to do]

This is what i am getting on browser

[image: This is what i am getting on browser]

Comment: Check the server host settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not shure if you can do proper deployment just by copying files.
In case you have a console connection to the server and in case you have a git repo of your project. You need a LAMP stack on your server, you could see how to do that here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

That is in case of Ubuntu, for other dist use something else.
You also need git and composer (Node.js if you need it, most of the time yes) installed on the server. 
Then you:

- Clone the repo on the server
- Install dependencies with: composer install from your folder
- Create a .env file with:

```
sudo nano .env
```

In this step you can copy .env-example to .env and apply settings that are good for   you.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

- for node-modules if required(if you have Node.js installed)

```
npm install
```

- change privileges for storage folder with

```
chmod -R -755 storage/
```

And if you have rest of the stuff you are good to go. By the reset of the stuff i mean having your virtual host set up, your domain propagated, your db ready. If you need help with virtual host here is something old but usefull:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Change in your .env:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

And enjoy fruits of your labour. Hope this helps